# Matching alternatives with By.CssSelector

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Using Selenium-WebDriver, depending on whether a page contains data or not I need to match two alternatives. The following works but not for empty results:

```cs
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(".property-price)")));
```

Rather disappointingly, this doesn't work at all.

```cs
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(":matches(.property-price, .no-results)")));
```

Is there any selector syntax supported by `By.CssSelector` that allows alternative classes?

I'm not wedded to CssSelector if you can express it with xpath or anything else. Just so long as I can match any of a list of possible readiness indicators. Indeed, `Until` seems to take a delegate or a lambda expression, but when I tried to supply a lambda expression with visions of using try/catch and `FindElement` the browser stalled for reasons I didn't understand. If you're feeling keen a tour of that approach would undoubtedly be more flexible in the long term.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `,` as a delimiter? like `By.CssSelector(".end-marker , .no-results")`

Comment: @frianH Actually I haven't tried that syntax. I'll give it a go. Since posting I have figured out how to do it by supplying a lambda expression, but your suggestion would be cleaner if it works.

Comment: Does your issue has solved?

Comment: @frianH I have a workaround that is a delegate containing a cascade of try/catch each testing a single class. For the question proper (an expression that matches multiple classes) I have no solution.